# How to use Power Query to import multiple CSV files into a single Excel worksheet as worksheet columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, power-query

I have a recent version of Excel (but very little experience with Excel). From a folder containing many `.csv` files, I want to import a few of the files *as columns* to a *single* Excel worksheet. I figured out how select the desired files by filename with a Power Query, and each file has the *same* number of rows. (They each also happen to have a single column, but I welcome a multicolumn solution.) A web search revealed that a Power Query could append rows from each file to produce a single column in a combined sheet, but that is not what I want. I also do *not* want to combine the columns into a summary column. As an example, if I have three `.csv` files after filtering in the Power Query editor, I would like to import these into a single sheet with three columns (one for each file). Ideally the result would be a single table, but that is of secondary importance.

How to proceed?

Comment: Unclear, perhaps an example will clear things up: How many columns per sheet on input and are they to be merged into one? Do you have a common key for combining the files or you want just to paste them horizontally? How many files?

Comment: @harrymc You can stick to the example I provided, and I'll generalized it as needed. As stated, there is currently one column per `.csv` file and I want them side by side, without any other "combining". What I need is a way to get the files from the query into one (1) sheet, side by side (i.e., appending columns not rows).

Comment: Do you mean that all CSVs contain each only one  column?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, as stated in the question. (While I welcome a solution that would work as well if they each had multiple columns, addressing the single column per file case would meet my current needs.)
What is important is that the CSV columns from the multiple files end up side by side in a single XLSX sheet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in Power Query, you will need some custom code.

I assume you are selecting the files from the `Data => From Folders` dialog,

The code below starts at that point, and then adds code that runs after you have filtered the table to select the requisite files.

- Read in the csv data into a column of tables
- Expand the tables column which puts all the data into a single column.
- Then, the magic:  use a custom function to Pivot the data using the file name
- Note that there are various arguments for the `Csv.Document` function which I have left out, not knowing anything about the data that you are accessing except that it is a csv document.

Read the code comments and also the reference in the custom function for more info.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\PQ Test"),

// Select (filter) the particular files you want, then

//Remove all except the "link" and file name columns
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Content", "Name"}),

//convert each csv to a Table
csvTables = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "csv", each Csv.Document([Content])),

//remove the column of links
remLinks = Table.RemoveColumns(csvTables,{"Content"}),

//Expand the tables into a single column
#"Expanded csv" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(remLinks, "csv", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"}),

//Pivot on the file name
pivot = fnPivotAll(#"Expanded csv","Name", "Column1")
in
    pivot
```

**Custom Function M Code**
***reNAME this query: fnPivotAll***

```
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

**Results**
*note that column headers are file names*

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but ... good grief. Is this need so uncommon?

Comment: @Alan First question I've seen here about it. But that may not be a good metric.  In any event, if my answer satisfies your problem, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as accepted. You can read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is the manual copy-and-paste of columns,
for the case where there are only a few files.

For other cases, the solution would be to use a VBA macro,
using the old
[Visual Basic for Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications).
For more information see the article
[Create or run a macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

I have found two rather similar VBA macros for joining CSV files
horizontally, all found within the same folder,
written for a variable number of columns.

I list the macros below, but I have not tested any of them.

**Macro 1**

This comes from the post
[Import multiple csv files in one excel spread sheet - include file name in the first row](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_365hp/import-multiple-csv-files-in-one-excel-spread/9f46b929-4f3f-4975-ab40-7598147abf57).
The macro here also renames the columns.

[image]

```
Sub GetFromCSVs()
  Dim WB As Workbook
  Dim R As Range
  Dim bFirst As Boolean
  Dim stFile As String
  Dim stPath As String
  stPath = "C:\Temp\CSVs\" ' change the path to suit
  stPath = "C:\Users\gebruiker\Documents\Excel\"
  stFile = Dir(stPath & "*.csv")
  bFirst = True
  Set R = Workbooks.Add(xlWorksheet).Sheets(1).Range("A1")
  Do Until stFile = ""
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(stPath & stFile, ReadOnly:=True)
    If bFirst Then
      WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Copy Destination:=R.Offset(1)
      Set R = R.Offset(, 1)
      bFirst = False
    End If
    R.Value = Left(stFile, Len(stFile) - 4)
    WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(2).Copy Destination:=R.Offset(1)
    Set R = R.Offset(, 1)
    WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    stFile = Dir  ' next file
  Loop
End Sub
```

**Macro 2**

This macro comes from the article
[How to import multiple csv files in one excel spread sheet](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_365hp/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-in-one-excel/f2922951-397e-4ef7-95d9-c6c0be4129bc).

[image]

```
Sub GetFromCSVs()
  Dim WB As Workbook
  Dim R As Range
  Dim bFirst As Boolean
  Dim stFile As String
  Dim stPath As String
  stPath = "C:\Temp\CSVs\" ' change the path to suit
  stFile = Dir(stPath & "*.csv")
  bFirst = True
  Set R = Workbooks.Add(xlWorksheet).Sheets(1).Range("A1")
  Do Until stFile = ""
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(stPath & stFile, ReadOnly:=True)
    If bFirst Then
      WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=R
      Set R = R.Offset(, 2)
      bFirst = False
    Else
      WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(2).Copy Destination:=R
      Set R = R.Offset(, 1)
    End If
    WB.Close saveChanges:=False
    stFile = Dir()  ' next file
  Loop
End Sub
```